# How to set location of profiles.yml and dbt_project.yml files in DBT?

Tags: sql, database, etl, dbt

Running `dbt debug --config-dir` shows the incorrect location.

E.g.)

```
12:35:52  Running with dbt=1.0.3
12:35:52  To view your profiles.yml file, run:

open /The/wrong/directory
```

How do I tell DBT that I've moved the `profiles.yml` & `dbt_project.yml` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dbt run --help` shows that there are two flags for this specific purpose.

```
  --project-dir PROJECT_DIR
                        Which directory to look in for the dbt_project.yml file. Default is the current working directory and its parents.
  --profiles-dir SUB_PROFILES_DIR
                        Which directory to look in for the profiles.yml file. Default = /Users/username/.dbt
```

The command you'll want to run is:

```
dbt run --project-dir /path/to/new --profiles-dir /path/to/new
```

Comment: `--profiles-dir /path/to/new/profiles.yml_file` won't work. You must specify a folder for `--profiles-dir` and in that folder, your profiles file must be named `profiles.yml`

Comment: Well spotted @zoltanctoth. This was implied in my answer as the filepath reads `--profiles-dir /path/to/new/dbt_project.yml_file`. Meaning that the location *must* contain a `profiles.yml` file.

So, thanks for making this important clarifying point :)

Answer (score 3):

In your prompt type: `export DBT_PROFILES_DIR=/path/to/folder`

This command will reassign the location of your `profiles.yml` to the folder mentioned in `/path/to/folder`.

Once it is done, run: `dbt debug --config-dir`

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the two environment variable:

- `DBT_PROJECT_DIR`
- `DBT_PROFILES_DIR`

to set the locations of the folder.

Here is the complete search order for `profiles.yml`:

1. `--profiles-dir option`
2. `DBT_PROFILES_DIR` environment variable
3. current working directory (new)
4. `~/.dbt/` directory

and the search order for `dbt_project.yml`:

1. `--project-dir option`
2. `DBT_PROJECT_DIR` environment variable (new)
3. current working directory

Comment: Note: DBT_PROJECT_DIR only came live in Mar 2023: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/pull/6659